# Getting Started with Neo4j and Ruby - Error: Neo4j::DeprecatedSchemaDefinitionError in Books#index - id_property is the root of the issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Getting Started with Neo4j and Ruby

https://neo4j.com/developer/ruby-course/

I followed this instruction.

```
rails new asset_portal -m http://neo4jrb.io/neo4j/neo4j.rb -O
cd asset_portal
rake neo4j:install[community-latest]
rake neo4j:start
```

I got the projects setup and neo4j server started.

And then I followed the instruction to create scaffold for user, asset, category and book.

And then I changed the book model to [image]

as instructed.

[image]

And I changed this too as instructed.

Now I run the migration, and start the server.

```
rake neo4j:migrate
rails s
open http://localhost:3000/books
```

I got the migration error

```
Neo4j::DeprecatedSchemaDefinitionError in Books#index
Some schema elements were defined by the model (which is no longer supported), but they do not exist in the database.  Run the following to create them if you haven't already:

rake neo4j:generate_schema_migration[constraint,Book,isbn]


And then run `rake neo4j:migrate`
```

I followed the instruction, and run

```
rake neo4j:generate_schema_migration[constraint,Book,isbn]
rake neo4j:migrate
```

I still get the same error.

I found a neo4j git link which is talking about the same error, https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/1356. It says "id_property" is the root of the issue. But I could not get clear answer what should I do from this thread.

And I am following the instruction from Neo4j manual to change the book model to

```
id_property :isbn
```

Someone else must already run into this bug and solved this issue. (Maybe Neo4j manual is out of date now). Please help.

I am running this on Mac. And I just updated rake, ruby on my Mac, before I started this project.

```
$ rails --version
Rails 5.2.2

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this line, from the manual (manual is out of date)

```
id_property :isbn
```

from the instruction.

Instead, I use

```
rake neo4j:generate_schema_migration[constraint,Book,isbn]
```

This will make

```
- CONSTRAINT ON ( book:Book ) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

Before I run

```
rake neo4j:migrate
```

This should solve the problem.